# Installing SciPy when dependencies are in non-default folder

Tags: python, installation, scipy, pip

I have Python 2.7.11 64bit installed on Win7, but I don't have write access to where Python is installed. Therefore I've created a new folder

> C:\Python27-accessible\Lib\site-packages

where I intend to install all my packages using pip. For this purpose I've added

```
[global]
target=C:\Python27-accessible\Lib\site-packages
```

to `%APPDATA\pip\pip.ini` and added `C:\Python27-accessible\Lib\site-packages` to `PYTHONPATH` in User Environment Variables.

This works for a number of packages like `numpy, pandas` etc.. But when it comes to `SciPy` I encounter an issue, since the installer seems to look for dependencies in the original folder

```
PS C:\> pip install --proxy http://proxy_address:port SciPy
Collecting SciPy
  Using cached scipy-0.18.1.tar.gz
Building wheels for collected packages: SciPy
  Running setup.py bdist_wheel for SciPy ... error
  Complete output from command "c:\program files\python\2.7.11\python.exe" -u -c "import setuptools, tokenize;__file__='
c:\\users\\g50644\\appdata\\local\\temp\\pip-build-qj_pis\\SciPy\\setup.py';f=getattr(tokenize, 'open', open)(__file__);
code=f.read().replace('\r\n', '\n');f.close();exec(compile(code, __file__, 'exec'))" bdist_wheel -d c:\users\g50644\appd
ata\local\temp\tmpzn7ze1pip-wheel- --python-tag cp27:
  lapack_opt_info:
  openblas_lapack_info:
    libraries openblas not found in ['c:\\program files\\python\\2.7.11\\lib', 'C:\\', 'c:\\program files\\python\\2.7.1
1\\libs']
    NOT AVAILABLE
```

Does somebody know how to overcome this problem without the need of write access to `c:\program files\python\2.7.11\`?

Comment: just use anaconda and scipy will be included. No point of reinventing the wheel

Comment: @nickpick unfortunately not an option at my current job.

Comment: So the employer is actively working against you? Do you need it for yourself or do you install the package for other people?

Comment: Priviliges over own software in big corporate banks can be quite the hazzle, unfortunately.

Comment: If it's for yourself you should still be able to install anaconda, just don't put it in program files, but in appdata instead. It works for my bank. You won't need any admin privileges. Then use pycharm to select anaconda as your primary interpreter. and you'll have all libraries at your disposal.

Comment: @nickpick yeah I know actually. But my boss doesn't support this workaround and prefer all installations through the actual internal IT service portal where anaconda isn't available. I agree that it seems as an unnecessary hazzle.

Comment: Can I ask which bank that is? If you boss wants to have it done via internal package, then either ask anaconda to be added or have the tech support install it for you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

An alternative approach might be to download the whl file here and the use pip on this file:
http://www.lfd.uci.edu/~gohlke/pythonlibs/#scipy

`pip install scipy-0.18.1-cp27-cp27m-win_amd64.whl` (assuming you use the 64 bit)

My preferred solution: Use Anaconda, install it into your appdata folder  (which is the standard folder anyway) and use Pycharm to select it as your interpreter for a project (it will automatically be the standard interpreter even if you don't want to use anaconda as it will set the necessary variables in your use account, which doesn't need admin privileges either).

That way you have all packages installed without the need for any admin privileges. Also if you will need to add more packages in the future you'll have no problems as it will be in a folder where you have full write permission.

Comment: So eventually I've installed Anaconda again. BUT when I try to upgrade SciPy then I encounter the exact same problem as before; NOT AVAILABLE message. Any suggestions? I've used pip and not conda, since I can't seem to connect to conda repos through a proxy.

Comment: Never mind. Now it works, I've simply had to use https proxy instead of http (which I normally use) - no clue why. Anyways, it seems like I am up to speed now.

Comment: That's why sometimes it's easier to download the whl file, but good it worked